# Как посчитать максимальный элемент матрицы через функцию?

Tags: pascal

Помогите разобраться. Изначально ввел и вывел матрицу через процедуру, а дальше хочу обратиться к этой матрице(а не вводить новую) и обрабатывать ее. Выдает максимум как 0. Почему?

Как сделать так чтобы я один раз ввел матрицу, а далее уже через разные функции и процедуры обрабатывал ее?

Вот код : http://pastebin.com/CHMBUGx4

```
Program brain;
uses crt;

type
matr= array [1..50, 1..50] of integer;
var
a:matr;

procedure vvod(i, j, n: integer ; a:matr); //ввод матрицы
begin
 for i:=1 to n do
  for j:=1 to n do
  read(a[i,j]);
  readln;
begin
 for i:=1 to n do
 begin
  for j:= 1 to n do 
   write('   ',a[i, j]);
   writeln;
   writeln;
end;
end;
end;

function maxelem {var a:matr;}( n:integer; var a:matr):real;
var
//a:matr;
max:real;
i, j: integer;
begin

 max:=a[1,1];
   for i:=1 to n do

     for j:=1 to n do

       if max < a[i,j] then  max:=a[i,j];

       writeln('max= ', max);




  end;


begin

var n, i, j:integer;
writeln('введите размерность квадратной матрицы');
write ('n= ');
readln( n);
writeln('впишите элементы квадратной матрицы');
writeln;
vvod(i,j,n,a);
maxelem(n, a);
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я помню Паскаль, вместо

```
procedure vvod(i, j, n: integer ; a:matr)
```

нужно использовать

```
procedure vvod(i, j, n: integer ; var a:matr)
```

Т.е. вам надо передать матрицу по ссылке, чтоб работа шла с реальной матрицей.

Второй вариант - не передавать матрицу в процедуры и функции вовсе, а работать с глобальным объектом.

Answer (score 0):

```
type
    matr= array [1..50, 1..50] of integer;
var
    // Здесь переменная a объявляется как глобальная, с ней и нужно работать
    a:matr;

// Здесь не передается глобальная переменная, а создается новая локальная
procedure vvod(i, j, n: integer ; a:matr); //ввод матрицы
// Заменить на
procedure vvod(i, j, n: integer); //ввод матрицы
// Либо возвращать матрицу и присваивать ее глобальной переменной a

// Тут тоже самое
function maxelem ( n:integer; var a:matr):real;
// Заменить на
function maxelem ( n:integer):real;

begin
    vvod(i,j,n);
    maxelem(n);
end.
```